# What is the probability a random walk hits x before it hits y?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, random-walk

This problem was motivated by my bitcoin trading and recalling some of my math education back in the day. I thought I'd ask people who know this much better than I...

Suppose there is a continuous, log-normally distributed random walk -- Brownian Motion basically. (As an aside, it's a martingale, right? But not necessarily a Markov process because the variance / volatility may depend on the past slightly while the mean does not.)

Anyway, my question is, suppose the X[t] is currently = c. What is the probability, given positive numbers x and y, that X[s] = x for some s while X[u] != y for any u between t and s. That is, X hits x before y?

I am asking because this seems to me like a winning strategy:

1. Buy and hold 10 bitcoins on http://bitfinex.com
2. Take a short position (borrow and sell) 5-6 bitcoins on margin
3. Since the value of the bitcoins can go arbitrarily low before finally coming back up and giving me profit in a finite time, I can close my margin position when the price has sufficiently dropped and wait until my actual coins go back to what they were worth, so I don't have to worry about not making a profit eventually, assuming actual log-normal distribution.
4. If the value of the bitcoins goes up, however, my bitcoins supporting the margin also go up in value. So it can keep covering the margin for a very long time. I only get margin-called if the value of the bitcoins shoots up 10x or so and doesn't come back down.
5. So here's the dilemma. What are the chances that the value of the bitcoins goes up 10x and NEVER goes below the point at which I borrowed+sold them? Or similarly, if it goes down 10x and NEVER goes back up to the starting point?

According to the efficient market hypothesis, any strategy with martingales won't yield a positive expected value, so if the process is really a martingale, then this should all even out and in the long run I will make the same as if I just held the bitcoins and didn't do anything, which if it's a martingale is 0 profit, right?

Answer (score 3):

I think you may  need to define your process and your question more precisely.  If you're talking about a discrete-time process (or one that changes only by discrete jumps) with a continuous distribution, the probability that it ever hits (exactly) $x$ is $0$.  If you're talking about a martingale that has continuous sample paths, if $c$ is between $x$ and $y$, the probability $p$ of hitting $x$ before $y$ is exactly what you need to have $0$ expected gain by stopping the first time you hit $x$ or $y$: thus $c = p x + (1-p) y$, or $p = \dfrac{c - y}{x - y}$.

As for the probability of never coming back to the starting point, that may be $0$ in typical models... but "never" is a very long time.  And any particular model is not going to reflect reality forever.

Comment: Thanks for that. I guess the continuous model fits my needs. The discrete model would too, except I'd use intervals (-inf, x] and [y, inf). I just want to know if my strategy is likely to make a profit in the long term